# I have learned most of the syntax of php and have created some simple scripts? now what is the next step?

Tags: php

I want to learn to create and modify php applications. I learned most of the common syntax by now and understand basic concepts like connecting to mysql and post and get http methods, but still not sure how to go about creating something complex like a full application with libraries and how it all connects together. I tried analyzing already existing apps and get really confused just by looking at codes that call on other files with many custom functions which are unreadable to my eyes. I hear about frameworks and about libraries, but I am pretty confused in this step of the way. What would be the concept I am missing to learn to make the leap towards creating complex applications. Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Usually we prefer questions that are *not* opinion based, and that have a definite answer. This way we can make sure that each question can receive the *best* answer possible. Can you narrow down your question any?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is always a lot to learn with php. It's a constant learning curve.

Some of the things that I can let you know.

Firstly make sure you follow best practices. There is always the temptation to cut corners, because php allows it.
Here is a guide to coding with php the right way which I found useful
http://www.phptherightway.com/

There are many php frameworks out there these days and choosing the right one that fits your needs is important. Some are more powerful or flexible than other, but some also have a steeper learning curve than others.
http://www.hongkiat.com/blog/best-php-frameworks/
Article that may help. Most of the frameworks will have a "how to" which will guide you through the process.
I personally use ZF2, but Laravel has gained a lot of popularity these days.

Also make sure you take a look at some of the places like tutsplus, project treehouse and other great learning resources.

Good luck, and I hope you make some amazing applications.